# FreeType producing asymmetric glyphs

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

So I am trying to implement font rendering with signed distance fields in my graphics engine.

For this I am using the FreeType library to generate Glyphs of all the letters. Specifically I am trying to load monochrome bitmaps like this:

```
FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER | FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO)
```

And then I extract all the bits from the glyph buffer and put it into a monochrome black white texture that I can display on the screen for testing purposes.

My Code for extracting the bits and putting it into a byte array:

```
FT_Bitmap bm = face->glyph->bitmap;

FT_Bitmap mono;
FT_Bitmap_New(&mono);
//convert from 8 pixel per byte to 1 pixel per byte
FT_Bitmap_Convert(ft, &bm, &mono, 1);
//set each byte from 0/1 to 0/255
for (int y = 0; y < mono.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mono.width; x++) {
        mono.buffer[y * mono.width + x] *= 255;
    }
}
```

My problem however is, that the glyphs FreeType produces seem to be asymmetric.

For example this is the letter M with a font pixelsize of 64 using the font OpenSans-Regular:

[image]

And this is the letter M with the same Font with a pixelsize of 1024:

[image]

I have tried this with multiple fonts, multiple font sizes etc. and certain glyphs always stay asymmetric.
Also note that I read the textures pixel data manually to verify that OpenGL's texture scaling or whatever doesn't cause the error.

Any ideas as to why FreeType seems to be producing asymmetric glyphs or could anyone tell me if this would even be a problem when later rendering text?

Edit: I now extract the bits using library functions, so the mistake must be somewhere in FreeType.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm about to start following a learnopengl tutorial.

Comment: Yeah he uses FreeType aswell but he doesn't use signed distance fields.

Comment: "*Yeah he uses FreeType aswell but he doesn't use signed distance fields.*" FreeType doesn't generate "signed distance fields. It just rasterizes glyphs. It's not clear to me what your problem with the asymmetry here is.

Comment: I am aware that I need to generate the signed distance field myself. For this however I need a monochrome bitmap which I am trying to generate for each character of a font using FreeType. The problem with the asymmetry is that the generated glyphs seem to be inaccurate, because why would my 'M' character look like in the image above and not basically the left side mirrored?

Comment: I added code for how I extract the data from the FreeType bitmap.

Comment: It's almost definitely just how the glyph looks in the font you've chosen at the specified resolution. You can try to tweak some of the hinting parameters, but the effect won't be drastic enough to make it look symmetric. Try rendering at a much higher resolution and zoom in to see if it's just how the glyph is?

Comment: I added another image showing the exact same glyph of the same font with a resolution of 1024 and as you can see (on the top left and top right) the problem still persists.
I also added the font I am using "OpenSans regular" and it doesn't seem like it should have this error.
I just don't understand why it would be this inaccurate? Does it even matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the assumption here that OpenSans is a font where all the glpyhs are symmetric. This is not the case, nor is it a FreeType bug. You can always send an email to the freetype list, but will probably be given the same answer.

It's not an inaccuracy because the font designer designed the M glyph to not by symmetric, for whatever reasons he chose. A lot of times, this will be done to increase readability. A little asymmetry will cause hinting engines to rasterize the glyph in a slightly different way that will be more legible or look more 'crisp'. Here are a few screenshots to prove that this is the case.

First, this is a heavily zoomed in screenshot of Windows 10/Chrome 55 rendering the glyph in the browser at the smallest size the website would allow me to select. While it does look symmetric at first glance, it is not.

[image: Chrome 55 screenshot]

Second, I downloaded the font and opened it in FontForge. If you look closely you can see that the curves on the inside edge of the two sides are actually slightly different. I also took a moment to look at the two points that define the bottom center of the M. Their positions are (848, 0) and (985, 0). The midpoint between these two points is (916.5, 0), however the two points that define the top edge of this part of the glyph are at (920, 256) and (928, 256). This is shifted slightly to the right.

[image: FontForge screenshot]

If you're looking for symmetric or otherwise simple fonts, look for fonts geared towards programmers or as console fonts. Arial, Consolas, Courier New, etc. will probably fit the bill pretty well.